# Fearing the Evolution of Coronavirus

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

As governments dread the evolution of a Coronavirus-variant that will not be susceptible to the new wave of vaccines, how would this fear be expressed in Latin?

The Romans, with no concept of vaccination, might have seen a vaccine as a defending thing; requiring a gerund: "defendendum" = "the defending (thing/ agent)"; "paratus ad defendendum" = "prepared for defending".

An (evolutionary) variant, in Latin, could be "progenies, ei" (feminine noun) = "race", "family", "progeny" (Oxford).

In Latin there are rules for dealing with verbs of fearing: if (as is normally the case) the fear relates to the future, the subordinate verb goes in the present subjunctive after a primary main verb or the imperfect subjunctive after a historic main verb.

> "imperium timet ne progenies morbi defendendum quod superet." =

> "The government fears that an (evolutionary) variant of the disease may/ will overcome any vaccine."

If the fear relates to the present or the past, the subordinate verb, while still subjunctive, will be in the same tense as it would be in English e.g. the perfect sunjunctive for the perfect tense:

> "imperium timet ne progenies morbi iam advenerit ut defendendum quod superet." =

> "The government fears that a variant of the disease has already arrived, that may overcome any vaccine."

Any thoughts?

EDIT: 19/6/2021:

In the light of Sebastian's comment about the use of "ut" & "quod" in the same clause, the second translation could be:

> "imperium timet ne progenies morbi iam advenerit quae defendendum ullum superet.";

where the "quae"-clause relates to antecedent, "progenies".

SECOND EDIT: 22/6/2021:

Using the present participle:

> "imperium timet ne progenies morbi iam advenerit quae (rem) defendentem ullum superet."

Comment: Can *imperium* fear? or do things in general?

Comment: d_e: If it can rule, it can fear, can't it? It could be changed to politicians ("Senatores") and the verbs put into third-person plural (Oxford gives "politician" = "vir rerum publicarum peritus"--a bit of a mouthful). Before I do this, are you sure?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just wondered because somewhere I read that neuter nouns usually are not the agent of verbs. don't know about *imperium*.

Comment: "vaccine as a defending thing; requiring a gerund" -- a present participle, surely? But seriously, just say *vaccinum*. Or if that's too modern for your taste, *[medicamen] praeservativum*.

Comment: @SEbastian Koppehel: I wanted the noun--"the defending..." and the verb element--it's doing something--driving away the virus. The present participle is adjectival, requiring something being described e.g. "res"; "...rem defendentem quod superet". The addition of "rem" looked clumsy. The use of "vaccinum" = "relating to a cow": yes, the cow(pox) was involved in the development of the first vaccine; but, I try to avoid the trap of using Latin words that look like English words e.g. "infestus" = "hostile"; not "infested". My main concern, as always, is that it's all grammatically correct--is it?

Comment: @tony A concern for me would be that I, at least, do not understand what the *ut* and the *quod* are doing in those sentences.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Thank you. The use of "quis"/ "quod", after "ne" = "any". I wondered whether the new ("ut") clause should still continue this sequence.  It can be changed to "ullum". The "ut" = "that"; literaly, "with the result that"--which doesn't quite fit; but, then, I have been castigated for being too literal-minded.  The use of "ut" is massaged a little. A good way to learn something is to get it wrong the first time.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel:  I've added an edit of the second translation. It retains the subjunctive, after "quae",  because it is still to do with fearing and/ or the authority is not the writer's but the government's. Is this better, please?

Comment: Why not use _remedium_?

Comment: @Rafael: I wanted the verbal part of the gerund--the vaccine is doing something--stopping the virus.

Comment: @tony The gerund does not refer to *something that verbs* but to *the act of verbing.* For the former meaning, you want the present participle, which on its own (= used as a substantive) can mean *something that verbs.* Participles need no obvious referent: e.g., *currentem video* 'I see someone running', *amantes osculantur* 'the lovers (= the loving ones) exchange kisses'.

Comment: I'm seconding @Anonym. The gerund is wrong here.

Comment: @Anonym: Thank you. The gerund-version translated literally: "...which may overcome any 'the defending.'", which is clearly wrong.  The present-participle version: "...which may overcome  any defending thing (any vaccine).", which is more like it.